# I cannot draw objects and have them move on the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I can draw static things to the screen, but I want to make them move with user key input. I don't know what to do, I've been searching and searching and haven't come up with an answer yet. Please help!

```
package com.Game.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JFrame
{

final static int width = 500;
final static int height = 500;

public int x = 250;
public int y = 250;
public int changeX = 10;
public int changeY = 10;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Game();
}

public Game()
{
    KeyListener listener = new KeyListening();
    addKeyListener(listener);
    setFocusable(true);
    DrawingStuff drawingstuff = new DrawingStuff();
    add(drawingstuff);
    setSize(width, height);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public class DrawingStuff extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Hey there!", 300, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}

public class KeyListening implements KeyListener
{
    DrawingStuff drawingstuff = new DrawingStuff();
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            y = y + changeY;
            System.out.println("Hey");
            drawingstuff.repaint();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {


    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {


    }
}


public void update()
{

}
}
```

***EDIT:*** Fixed it. I took away the key listener stuff in the constructor method, added a command to focus on "drawingstuff" in the constructor method, and, most importantly, added this bit of code to the end of the constructor method:

```
while(true)
    {
        drawingstuff.repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Even if that works, IMHO, doing `#repaint()` in a while-loop isn't the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `KeyListening` object has a reference to a different `DrawingStuff` object than the one you added to your UI inside the `Game` constructor.

```
public class KeyListening implements KeyListener
{
    DrawingStuff drawingstuff = new DrawingStuff();
    ...
```

You should pass a `DrawingStuff` reference to the `KeyListening` instance so that it can tell the right object to repaint itself.